# Seleccionar toda una fila - JTable Java

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago click en el checkbox solo se selecciona la celda en donde esta el checkbox, como hago para que se seleccione toda la fila al momento que seleccione el checkbox.
Esta es mi clase Render.

```
public class Mirender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column)
    {
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    //Alinear al centro los valores de una fila del JTable
    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías añadir algo de tu código, que hayas intentado. Es muy difícil ayudarte desde cero.

Comment: ya esta @cnbandicoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar tienes que permitir selección de filas y prohibir selección de columnas con:

```
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
```

Puedes acceder las filas seleccionadas con

```
int[] selected = table.getSelectedRows();
```

Comment: y como haria para que se mantenga el seleccionado, osea hago click al checkbox y se selecciona toda la fila, hago en otro click e igual se selecciona toda la fila(manteniendose el primero seleccionado). @StefanNolde